# Terminal outputting extraneous process info when I switch windows

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

When I run a command that spawns a new window from the terminal, I see output like this:

```
1   HIToolbox                           0x00000001935cc5c8 _ZN15MenuBarInstance22EnsureAutoShowObserverEv + 120
2   HIToolbox                           0x00000001935cc188 _ZN15MenuBarInstance14EnableAutoShowEv + 60
3   HIToolbox                           0x000000019356f310 SetMenuBarObscured + 372
4   HIToolbox                           0x000000019356eee8 _ZN13HIApplication15HandleActivatedEP14OpaqueEventRefhP15OpaqueWindowPtrh + 172
5   HIToolbox                           0x0000000193568fcc _ZN13HIApplication13EventObserverEjP14OpaqueEventRefPv + 296
6   HIToolbox                           0x000000019352fcd0 _NotifyEventLoopObservers + 176
7   HIToolbox                           0x000000019356896c AcquireEventFromQueue + 432
8   HIToolbox                           0x0000000193557c84 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 320
9   HIToolbox                           0x0000000193557b2c _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 72
10  AppKit                              0x000000018d0fd84c _DPSNextEvent + 632
11  AppKit                              0x000000018d0fc9dc -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 728
12  SDL2                                0x0000000101285684 SDL2 + 71300
13  SDL2                                0x00000001012f7238 SDL_DYNAPI_entry + 191160
14  love                                0x00000001019912f8 _ZN4love5event3sdl5Event4pumpEv + 168
15  love                                0x0000000101897f2c _ZN4love5event6w_pumpEP9lua_State + 44
16  Lua                                 0x0000000100f10908 Lua + 18696
17  love                                0x0000000100d472e8 love + 13032
18  dyld
```

If I switch windows while that process is open, I see similar output again.

This occurs with any command that spawns a new window. In my case, I observed it with two commands that open game development tools:

- `/Applications/love.app/Contents/MacOS/love` which opens the Love2D runtime.
- `/Applications/PICO-8.app/Contents/MacOS/pico8` which opens Pico-8

These programs normally only output print statements from my game code or uncaught exceptions that crash the game. I started seeing this issue a couple of months ago.

How can I get rid of this extraneous output?

Comment: What command? No one can hope to help if we don't know what you're trying to run.

Comment: Would you consider redirecting the command output like `foo > /dev/null 2>&1` an acceptable solution?

Comment: @bmike no, suppressing the output would not be a good solution for me. these programs provide useful output as well as the cruft I pasted above. I've added more context to the original question about the commands I'm running. They are part of my game development tooling, so they print error messages and log statements from the games I'm building.

Comment: You claim "This occurs with any command that spawns a new window". Does it also happen if you run Safari or Mail from the command line, or only with the two dev environments mentioned?

Comment: The output is a crash - so is a bug in love or its dependencies. Does love work if run as an app from the Finder or via open?